# http always redirects to https in my localhost

Tags: php, typo3

I have been running TYPO3 project which is copied from live system and I want to run in my localhost, currently my php version is 5.6 and TYPO3 version is 4.7.

So, when I am trying to access http://192.168.0.74/projectname/ then it always redirects to https://192.168.0.74/projectname/.

I removed .htaccess also.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: It redirect no matter which project you go?

Comment: it returns me like this "This site can’t be reached" and page is blank: Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: You might get the answer here
https://www.superuser.com/questions/565409/chrome-how-to-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with phpMyAdmin, which is an administrative interface for accessing a MySQL or MariaDB database, so I've removed the phpmyadmin tag.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 can be configured to force HTTPS, and that is likely the case here. You can check your template settings for config.baseURL and/or config.absRefPrefix to see if that is the case.

Go to Template | (Home Page) | Template Analyzer and scroll to "View the complete TS listing." Then search within the page for https to see if that is your situation.

You need your .htaccess file if you want realURL to work. Just make sure that is not requiring HTTPS.